# How to conserve the pdf layout after converting content from English to French using Python

Tags: python, pdf, python-pdfkit

I am working on a simple application which will help me to convert all my pdf files which have text in English to French text as pdf. I have worked on a simple proof of concept which helps me to iterate over the given file and convert all text into French. Now I am stuck on saving the converted french text into a pdf with a similar structure of the original English version.

```
import PyPDF2
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('any_english.pdf', 'rb'))
write_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()

for i in range(number_of_pages):
    page = read_pdf.getPage(i)
    page_content = page.extractText()
    print translator.translate(page_content, dest='fr').text

    // Save the converted version text in french into a pdf conserving structure as original pdf
```

**Note

All contents in the pdf are text format not image.

Comment: The .extractText() method strips any formatting information about the page, and doesn't even guarantee you get the text back in any correct "order", as far as I know.  You'll be unable to recreate the page's structure and format with this method.  I don't know of a way to do what you're looking to do with this library.

Comment: Any other methods to accomplish this task? @DanielHarms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no easy ways to open, edit and rewrite pdfs in Python. However, depending on the complexity of the PDF/structure you might have success converting the PDF to HTML, translating and then generating a PDF from the HTML.

For converting PDF to HTML, there is [pdf2html](http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/) which has a basic [Python wrapper](https://github.com/mgedmin/pdf2html).

Once the translation is done you can reverse this process with various degrees of success using e.g. [weasyprint](http://weasyprint.org/), [html2pdf](https://github.com/nbudin/html2pdf) (Mac only), [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) (requires Qt).

Comment: I am searching for an example.

Comment: @BastinRobin thanks for accepting —  did you manage to make it work for you? Let me know if you need some more help in getting a working example up and running.

Comment: can you help me with an example? @mfitzp

Comment: @BastinRobin can't give full example now (away for a few days) but generally: use subprocess module to run external pdf2html to generate html. Open the html and run translator.translate over it, save to a new file. Then weasyprint using subprocess to generate the pdf output (new file).

Answer (score 1):

Basically you cant directly  create a PDF file in a specific format.
But you can try  writing your data in xhtml format then convert into .pdf using xhtml2pdf.
Hope this might help you in your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [textract](https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_package.html?highlight=process#textract.parsers.process)

```
import textract
text = textract.process('path/to/a.pdf', language='fr')
```

by default it preserves the layout

Comment: If it did it no longer does apparently.